# Represent the transformation with respect to the standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Consider a linear transformation from $R^2$ to $R^2$ defined via:
>
> $$\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 3\end{matrix} \right) \mapsto \left(\begin{matrix} 3 \\ 1\end{matrix} \right)$$ and $$\left(\begin{matrix} -1 \\ 3\end{matrix} \right) \mapsto \left(\begin{matrix} 3 \\ 2\end{matrix} \right)$$
> Represent the transformation with respect to the standard basis

It has been some time I have tried to understand this problem, and I have seen solutions to problems similar to this and I still do not understand it. Those solutions talk about images of $e_1$ and $e_2$ (which are the standard vectors of the standard basis), but I don't know what the heck they are talking about.

Comment: What is $e_1$, and what is its image?  What is $e_2$, and what is its image?  Once you write down these as columns, you will quickly build a matrix that represents the transformation.

Comment: Okay, but do you know what $e_1,e_2$ are?  Image just means applying the transformation to these (input) vectors, to obtain corresponding output.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Once you get an answer (for instance, we have $e_1 = \frac12\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 \\ 3\end{smallmatrix} \right) - \frac12\left(\begin{smallmatrix} -1 \\ 3\end{smallmatrix} \right)$), you can use the fact that you know what those two are sent to, and that the transformation is linear to figure out where $e_1$ and $e_2$ goes.

Answer (score 2):

We can represent a linear map: $F:\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ using a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$, generically, we can write:

$$\mathbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$$

Applying this to the vector $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3\end{pmatrix}^{T}$, we have:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a+3b \\ c + 3d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Similarly, applying it to the vector $\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 3\end{pmatrix}^{T}$, we have:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-a+3b \\ -c+3d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$$

We therefore have a system of 4 linear simultaneous equations with 4 variables $a, b, c$ and $d$:

$$\begin{align*}a+3b &= 3 \\ c+3d &= 1 \\ 3b-a &= 3 \\ 3d - c &= 2\end{align*}$$

Solving these we get:

$$a=0,\quad b=1,\quad c = -\frac{1}{2},\quad d=\frac{1}{2}$$

We can thus write our transformation matrix describing the linear map, as:

$$\mathbf{A} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 2 \\ -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This is in the standard basis where our basis vectors are $\hat{\boldsymbol{e}}_{1} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^{T}$ and $\hat{\boldsymbol{e}}_{2} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{T}$ as we are implicitly writing the vectors with the known transformations as linear combinations of the standard basis vectors. (i.e. $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3\end{pmatrix}^{T} = \hat{\boldsymbol{e}}_{1} + 3\hat{\boldsymbol{e}}_{2}$

Comment: @Rinzler: That's close.  If $B$ is a "change of basis" matrix that converts coordinates with respect to (non-standard) basis $\mathscr{B}$ into standard basis coordinates, and if $A$ represents the transformation with respect to standard basis coordinates, then $C = B^{-1}AB$ represents the transformation wrt $\mathscr{B}$ basis coordinates.

Comment: @Rinzler:  Right.  What it means for $A$ to represent the transformation (wrt standard coordinates) is that the transformation sends vector $v$ to vector $Av$.

Answer (score 2):

A vector can be decomposed regarding a basis, esp. the standard basis:
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x \\
y
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
x
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
0
\end{matrix}
\right)
+
y
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right)
= x e_1 + y e_2
$$
so a linear transformation $A$ acting on a vector can be calculated by $A$ acting on the base vectors.
$$
A
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x \\
y
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
x\,A
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
0
\end{matrix}
\right)
+
y\,A
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
x \, A e_1 + y \, A e_2
$$
The matrix of $A$ can be seen as
$$
A = \left((Ae_1) (Ae_2)\right)
$$
So from
$$
A
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
3
\end{matrix}
\right)
= 1\,A e_1 + 3\, A e_2 =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
3 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\quad
A
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-1 \\
3
\end{matrix}
\right)
= -1\,A e_1 + 3\, A e_2 =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
3 \\
2
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
one can take the sum and difference:
$$
6\, A e_2 =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
6 \\
3
\end{matrix}
\right)
\quad
2\,A e_1 =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 \\
-1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
This gives
$$
A = \left((Ae_1) (Ae_2)\right) =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1/2 & 1/2
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$